# limit of sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, asymptotics

I have the problem to compute next double sum
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(3n-k)^j{n\choose k}A^{n-k}B^k\;,
\end{equation}
being $j\gg1$ an integer number and $0\leq A,B\leq 1$. In order to deal with this expression, my idea was to approximate the inner sum and to convert the outer one into an integral (evaluating it maybe numerically if there are no further approximations). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are there any bounds/relations between $A$ and $B$? Specifically, $A+B$ and $A/B$?

Comment: not really, they are in general independent quantities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the outer sum cannot start from $n=1$, as the denominator is zero there. This said, you can write
$$
(3n-k)^j=\frac{\partial^j}{\partial s^j}e^{s(3n-k)}\Big|_{s\to 0}\ .
$$
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(3n-k)^j{n\choose k}A^{n-k}B^k=\frac{\partial^j}{\partial s^j}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{s(3n-k)}{n\choose k}A^{n-k}B^k\Big|_{s\to 0}=\frac{\partial^j}{\partial s^j}\left[A^n e^{3 n s} \left(\frac{B e^{-s}}{A}+1\right)^n\right]\Big|_{s\to 0}\ ,
\end{equation}
and (assuming your outer sum starts from $n=2$) one has
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^j}{\partial s^j}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n-1}\left[A^n e^{3 n s} \left(\frac{B e^{-s}}{A}+1\right)^n\right]\Big|_{s\to 0}=\frac{\partial^j}{\partial s^j}\left[e^{2 s} \left(A e^s+B\right) \log \left(A e^{3 s}+B e^{2 s}+1\right)\right]\Big|_{s\to 0}\ ,
\end{equation}
where one uses $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^n}{n-1}=z \log(1+z)$. I checked that (for the outer sum starting from $n=2$), setting $j=5$, $A=1/3$ and $B=1/6$, your initial sum is $\approx 371.369...$ and the exact result (taking five derivatives) is $\frac{6620645}{19683}+\frac{259}{3} \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\approx 371.369...$

Comment: Indeed, the outer sum is starting from n=2 (corrected). Thank you for help, sure that your answer is working perfectly for all j integer. Since $j\gg1$ I was looking more for an approximation that does not involve j-derivatives

Comment: Uhm...I think that with some extra work you can perform the $j$-derivatives exactly and end up with a closed form valid for all $j$ - for example using the general Leibniz rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule ...to my taste, a closed formula is infinitely better than any approximation, but I agree that my answer above is somewhat unfinished. I will try to see whether I can get something better.